# How to configure the System Speaker?

Tags: audio, lubuntu

I want playing simple melodies with my laptop's System speaker (a tiny speaker in motherboard for beep codes). I load BeepXP64 for make a beep but it doesn't beep after loading BeepXP64. I think system speaker doesn't beep because of Windows 10. I tried with Lubuntu's terminal with write "beep" and press Enter, but it doesn't beep. I put # in "blacklist pcspkr" in blacklist.conf, but it still doesn't beep. What I should apply for playing simple melodies from system speaker. (I know my laptop had a system speaker and system speaker appears on Windows 10's device manager. Moreover, my laptop beeps when battery is very low on boot or BIOS setup and Boot menu.)[image: system speaker appears in Windows 10's device manager]

### Edit: My problem is solved with GRUB_INIT_TUNE over 5 months ago.

I find a reason to this problem.

It is probably the sound driver that doesn't support the system speaker, because the system speaker doesn't make any beeps.

I must change the sound driver.

Comment: Have you checked that the PC-speaker kernel module is loaded? What is the output of `lsmod | grep pcsp` ?

Comment: I tried this code few days ago, but it doesn't beep. I think system speaker is broken, but it still works on BIOS setup and boot (in low battery). I have few samples of my laptop's system speaker beep.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved with GRUB_INIT_TUNE.

Comment: @Paulo, note that this appears to be the OP, attempting to show us how they solved their own problem. user350165, could you spell this solution out a bit more?

Comment: @JeffSchaller You are right. Didn't notice that.

Comment: Now, I'm using Pardus for 3 days and my problem is solved with GRUB_INIT_TUNE 3 days ago.